# How should array spread notation work with NodeLists in Babel?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm aware that `querySelectorAll` returns something Array-like but not quite an Array. So in my code I'm iterating over it using the ES6 spread syntax:

```
const things = document.querySelectorAll('.things');
[...things].forEach(thing => thing.do());
```

If I write that exact code into the Chrome devtools console, it works as expected. However, Babel is transpiling it to ES5:

```
var things = document.querySelectorAll('.things');
[].concat(things).forEach(function(thing) { thing.do() });
```

`[].concat(things)` **does not** do the same as `[...things]`. The expected result is an array of nodes, but `concat` returns an array of NodeLists. So calling `thing.do()` results in an error since a NodeList has no `do` method.

Instead, an ES5-friendly way to use Array methods on the NodeList would be to call `slice` first, like `Array.prototype.slice.call(things)`.

So is Babel wrong to transpile down to `concat` for every use of array spread? Or is there a newer version or configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Sounds like you are using `loose: true` in your Babel presets, which disables the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Only evergreen browsers need to be supported

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`@@isConcatSpreadable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable) property on the `NodeList.prototype` to `true` to make it work correctly with `[].concat`.

```js
NodeList.prototype[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = true;
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log([].concat(divs));
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
```